# Why a double initialization in tabs.js?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

hey guys i was just going through the code of [tabs.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tab.js#L121)(its a bootstrap plugin )  , now there is a pritty compicated line of code in this plugin , see below :

```
if (!data) $this.data('bs.tab', (data = new Tab(this)))
```

you can find it on [line 121](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tab.js#L121). now if the above line of code is replaced with the below line of code :

```
data = new Tab(this) // using this works just fine , the console also does't throw any errors .
```

the plugin still functions the same , i have created an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5tztfocn/) :

so what is the following line being used then ??

```
$this.data('bs.tab', (data = new Tab(this)))
```

whats the Fundamental purposed of initializing `'bs.tab'` with `new Tab(this)` ??

One major reason i am asking this question is all(nearly) bootstrap plugins use such double initialization .

Answer (score 1):

You missed the line above it!

```
  var data  = $this.data('bs.tab')
  if (!data) $this.data('bs.tab', (data = new Tab(this)))
```

In pseudo-code

1. Get the tab associated with `$this`.
2. If there isn't a tab associated
   with `$this`, create one and associate it.

Comment: hey i did't miss the line above it LOL , i was aware of that ! , i am not sure i am following what ur saying still  , my question is why the extra initilization ? :(

Comment: It isn't an _extra_ initialization, it's the only initialization!  That function may be called any number of times.  The first time through, the data will be null on the first line, and so the constructor will be called by the second, and the resulting object stored in the variable; on subsequent tries, the variable will be assigned to that object on the first line and so the second line will be skipped.  Imagine I said, "Go read what it says on that white-board; if the white-board is blank, write your name there."  By that algorithm, everyone will know who looked at the board first.